# duplicating an object and keyframing without affecting the original object

Tags: keyframes, object-mode

So I duplicate an object and start animating the duplicate object. The original object then inherits the same keyframes from the duplicate object. When deleting the keyframes from the original object, the duplicate object also looses it's keyframes.

Any idea what it could be? I tried un-linking the object but that deletes it.

I want the duplicate object to have keyframes but the original object to remain static.

Comment: Hello, you have to go to Object > Relations > Make single user > animation to unlink the animation between your objects

Answer (score 0):

No worries I managed to find a solution with trial and error. within relations, picking object and animation. This singles the object and allows you to animate the duplicate object with out affecting the original object. Sorry all ^^
[image]